# Working with 2-D arrays in JS

Tags: javascript

I know that multi-dimensional arrays are not natively supported in JS, but I would like to shoehorn them in a calculation I'm doing.  For example, I have:

```
amn1 = new Array(4);
for (j = 0; j < amn1.length; j = j + 1) {
  amn1[j] = new Array(4);
}
amn1[0][0] = -8.72500;
amn1[0][1] = 1.88000;
amn1[0][2] = 0.741900;
amn1[0][3] = 0.752000;
amn1[1][0] = 0.83090;
amn1[1][1] = 0.11140;
amn1[1][2] = -0.528800;
amn1[1][3] = -0.555890;
amn1[2][0] = -0.13396;
amn1[2][1] = -0.06481;
amn1[2][2] = 0.126423;
amn1[2][3] = 0.128431;
amn1[3][0] = 0.01262;
amn1[3][1] = 0.00540;
amn1[3][2] = -0.009341;
amn1[3][3] = -0.009306;
for (u = 0; u < 4; u = u + 1) {
  for (n = 0; n < 4; n = n + 1) {
    amn1[u][n] = amn1[u][n] * logt + amn1[u][n];
  }
  loglambda = loglambda + amn1[u][n];
  loglambda = loglambda * logi;
}
```

Assume my script is linted and all variables are properly declared and initialized.  Now, checking to see if JS understands the contents of `amn1` in the inner loop, it does.  However, in the outer loop a check of the console output reveals `undefined`.  Keeping the logic the same, this works in a procedural language, but not here (I have a working version of this in Fortran).

Why does this not work?

Comment: I'm not clear from your question what you mean by "outer loop check of the console output reveals undefined"?  What are you attempting to output in the outer loop? Can you put a little more code in?  If you mean in the outer loop you're literally doing `console.log(amn1)`, then that should absolutely reveal that amn1 is an array (or at least [Object object], depending on what your environment is) unless something else is amiss that you're not showing in your sample.

Comment: Couple sidenotes, your syntax is a bit odd for JS.  `new Array(4)` sets the initial length of the array, bit doesn't limit it so most folks just do `[]`.  Loops are normally written, `for(var n=0;n<4;n++)`.  No big deals, just letting you know.

Comment: Good JS coding practice says that variable declarations should be grouped together.

Comment: If you mean your loop variables, that's not actually commonly done.  Loop variables are usually declared in the loop.  Further, the point I was making was less about the var and more about the `u = u+1` in your loops.  Most folks just do `u++`

Comment: your `amn1[u][n]` are always defined, it's `logt`, `logi` and `loglambda` that I don't see defined anywhere, causing your result to be undefined.

Comment: @user2727195 carefully read the question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dead simple :

```
loglambda = loglambda + amn1[u][n];
```

on that line your **N** will always be **4**.

Keeping in mind the size of your array :  you have only **j = [0,1,2,3]** for each **amn1[i][j]**.

Comment: So, `console.log(amn1[u][n]);` just above that line gives `undefined`. Why?

Comment: once again, because amn1[u][4] <- does not exist, you are locked to 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 for the second parameter, since you created nested array of 4 elements. Remember index starts from 0

Comment: Remember that `u < 4` has to be false before the loop stops executing, leaving you with `u` containing the value `4` after you leave the loop.

Comment: That's it.  Thanks Eugene.  Coming from a procedural background, that's behavior I'm not used to.